# appropriate machine learning algorithm for few (features) variables

Tags: machine-learning

I have a number of questions that there seem to not be a clear answer to.

1. What machine learning algorithm (naïve Bayes, SVM's, neuralnets, bayesian etc) is appropriate when your dataset has a large number of observations but few varaibles?
2. Is there a point of convergence on the number of features of a given dataset and when the efficiency of a machine learning algorithm supercedes traditional regression?
3. Is there a point in using a machine learning technique when the relationship between your variable of interest and features is largely linear amongst those few variables?

Comment: Are you doing regression or classification?

Comment: I am doing classification

Comment: So what do you mean by traditional regression in your second question?

Comment: I mean is there a point where using a machine learning algorithm provides a classifier than using logistic regression? All issues associated with linearity aside.

Comment: You seem to have a perfect setup for a traditional nonlinear regression, why bother with ML?

Comment: Thats a really good question and one I have thought about. This is largely due to mis-classification leading to potential harm. So the goal is to try to have a classifier be as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 1):

1. Neural nets always perform better with more data, So you should prefer neural nets. Also if the number of features are small,they can make new intermediate ones using their hidden layers.
2. You cannot really say. You have to try it out.
3. You should still try out ML methods like NN's as they are very powerful , and if indeed the relations are linear, they would learn to make that decision boundary. But as they are powerful, you should compare their validation performance with that of the linear regression to be sure. You can do hypothesis testing to check if the difference is significant. If it is not , you should prefer, Linear regression as it is a simpler model less prone to overfitting

Comment: I do feel like the No Free Lunch Theorem deserves a mention here, though. For example XGBoost has often seen extremely competitive performance compared to neural nets on tabular data.

Comment: There's a logical fallacy in the first statement, which seems to me to be  NN + More Data > NN, therefore NN + More Data > Other techniques + More Data.

Comment: I agree with the other comments here. With standard tabular data boosted trees is probably the way to go but a couple of options could be tried.  Neural nets have specific areas where they crush everything but standard tabular data isn't one of them. If you can get a NN to beat xgboost/lightgbm on standard data sets it is (in my experience and Kaggle's as well) the exception not the rule. Also I've never had good experiences with hypothesis testing in this context, OP should just look at CV and holdout results to determine the model.